# Searching in a folder with the search(q='') syntax doesn't return any files that don't have a space

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

so I have a program that needs check if a file exists in a folder or subfolder in a drive. Trying to run
`/drives/{driveid}/items/{folderid}/search(q='{fullfilename or partialfilename}')`
doesn't show anything for most files since they do not contain spaces. Searching for . shows only files with spaces which are outliers in the folder

Comment: Recently I've read a blog post that developers should prefer using /search/query endpoint instead of /drives/.../search. Maybe try to use /search/query https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/transition-to-microsoft-graph-search-endpoint-for-onedrive-and-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint REST API's search endpoint uses the Keyword Query Language (KQL) to perform searches. When using the q parameter in the search endpoint, you might encounter issues with certain characters. Spaces, for instance, may need to be handled in a specific way.

```
var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='example%20file.txt'";
$.ajax({
    url: endpointUrl,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Process the search results
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```